# Different Instance of a recyclerview adapter has same variable values

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview adapter that contains a list of customclass and display them in a list,
now in an activity i need multiple instance of this adapter,
but when i try this the result is wring.
when i add a new item to adapter_instance_1 it is ok, but when i want to addd item to adapter_instance_2 i see that there is another item in its list(thats from adapter_instance_1)
this is my adapter cpass definition

```
public class attachmentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<attachmentAdapter.attachmentViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<attachment> mUris;
    ....
    ....
    ....
}
```

and this is initializing adapters:

```
attachmentAdapter first_adapter = new attachmentAdapter(new ArrayList<>(),"","",this,null)

attachmentAdapter second_one = new attachmentAdapter(new ArrayList<>(),"","",this,null)
```

could you please tell me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: First its not clear what you want so update your question, second why would you need 2 adapters for same recyclerview?

Answer (score 0):

You need to differentiate those different view holders within the adapter class.

Comment: their viewholder should be same, the only difference is data items passed nin list. view is same, events are same and so on, just `ArrayList<attachment> mUris` should be different

Comment: clear the ArrayList everytime you initialize it, Except the first time since it is already empty.

Comment: this is not the prob.
when i add item to first_adapter, then add another in second_adapter and get count of items in second_adapter it said there is 2 records, but only is 1, understood?